# How to remove the time stamp on the right side of the fish shell?

Tags: command-line, customization, fish

Simple question, I'd like to remove the time stamp on the right hand side of the fish shell terminal screen:

On a sidenote, it would be even better to know how to customize it as in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Put this in your `config.fish` (or eg. `.config/fish/functions/fish_right_prompt.fish`):

```
 function fish_right_prompt
  #intentionally left blank
 end
```

By putting stuff in this function you can also customize that part of the prompt however you want to. Whatever is returned by this function becomes the prompt.

Comment: This solution did work when configuring it via the web interface didn't work. However, at least the web interface displays where the file is located (see tab _functions_ > _fish_right_prompt_).